# Basic set theory and probability

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove the following but they all seem too obvious to need a proof. For the third one, for exmple, should I argue something along the line of $A\cup A^c=U$? Thanks in advance.

$A=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)$

$P(A) = P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)$

$P(A)=1-P(A^c)$

$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a blanket answer for each of these, when you need to prove something like 
$$
   X = Y
$$
in the context of set theory (especially early on), what this really means is that you need to prove the following two statements:
$$
    X \subseteq Y \quad\mathrm{and}\quad Y \subseteq X 
$$

So, for example, your proof that the statement $A=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)$ is true should look like this:

"Suppose $a \in A$. Then ... so $a \in (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)$. This proves that $A \subseteq (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)$.

"Conversely suppose that $a \in (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)$. Then ... so $a \in A$. This proves that $(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)  \subseteq A$.

"This concludes the proof that $A=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)$."

The meat of the proof is then filling in those ellipsis (...) while being very careful to only use the axioms you are given and any theorems you have previously proven from those axioms.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got the first one now. But what about the third one?

Comment: The third one requires the probability axiom that $P(U) = 1$ and the thing you mentioned in your question $A\cup A^c = U$.